# problem scanning and scanning data from file

Tags: c, scanf

I'm having some trouble in extracting data from a file, I don't understand what's wrong, it works fine for single digit integers, but when the input is double digit, it doesn't scan the integers. Everything else is working.

Suppose the input is:

```
abc de,1,2,y
```

then the output is:

"abc de" 1 2 y
but when the input is

```
cde abc,21.31,y
```

the scan fails on `%d`:

```
fin1 = fscanf(fp1, "%20[^,]%*c%d %*c %d%*c %c%*c", name1, &code1, &season, &relevant);
```

Help would be nice. Also some input as you asked:

**Input:**

```
The Universe,2,3,Y|Zoo,7,3,N|The Hobbit,10,2,Y|True Lies,12,25,N|Animals,22,2,Y| Euphoria,35,5,Y
```

**Code**:

```c
FILE *fp1, *fserie;
char file1name[256], name1[21], relevant = 0, active = 0;
int code1, seasons, fin = 0,

while (1) {
    puts("Enter First File Name:");
    scanf("%s", file1name);

    if (!(fp1 = fopen(file1name, "r")))
    {
        printf("error in opening file %s !!!\n", file1name);
        continue;

    } else break;
}

if (!(fserie = fopen("series.txt", "w")))
{
    fclose(fp1);
    exit(1);
}

do
{
    fin1 = fscanf(fp1,"%20[^,]%*c %d%*c %d%*c %c%*c", name1, &code1, &season, &active1);

    if (relevant == 'y')
        fprintf(fserie,"%s,%d,%d\n", name1, code1, season);

} while (fin1 != EOF && fin2 != EOF);
```

Comment: Please show some sample data.

Comment: The Universe,2,3,Y
Zoo,7,3,N
The Hobbit,10,2,Y
True Lies,12,25,N
Animals,22,2,Y
Euphoria,35,5,Y 
....

Comment: Put it in the question where you can format it

Comment: i get the first 2 (The Universe,2,3,Y Zoo,7,3,N ) but after that it goes to hell

Comment: i dont understand

Comment: what do you mean by that

Comment: ok i've added some of the code and the samples

Comment: Replace your `%*c` with `','` (a comma). Though functionally equivalent it is much easier to read and ensures the character is a comma and not the 21st character of a longer string. Better as `" %20[^,],%d,%d,%c"` ***note:*** the space before `%20[^,]`

Comment: i've tried that it didnt work

Comment: See addition to the comment. Also note you will need to take a different approach if you have multiple inputs per-line separated by `'|'`. Perhaps `" %20[^,],%d,%d,%c%*[^|]|"`

Comment: yeahh that still doesnt work it just doesnt scan the int when it hits double digit input

Comment: the problem isnt with the lines since i used %*c for that it just throw it away it just doesnt scan the integers at double digit it drives me crazy because it should work.

Comment: i get the first couple of inputs just fine but the scan fails on the ints

Comment: `fin2` not defined.  Do not compare against `EOF`, instead `while (fin1 == 4);`

Comment: Is the data in the text file truly `"The Universe,2,3,Y|Zoo,7,3,N|The Hobbit,10,2,Y|True Lies,12,25,N|Animals,22,2,Y| Euphoria,35,5,Y"`?

Comment: fin2 is from the original source code i just didnt edit that part out it works fine, its a different scan thats irelevant i just forgot to edit it out

Comment: `while (fin1 != EOF` `fscanf` returns the number of items scanned __or__ EOF on error. There may be no errors, it may just return 0.

Comment: yeah out teacher watch too much tv.

Comment: you're trying to analyze irelevant things that working perfectly the only thing that doesnt work is the recieving integers it just fails scanning them on double digit if i play with input anything from range of 0-9 will scan perfectly but when its 10+ it just fails scanning and get into infinite loop

Comment: Suggesting those with decades of experience are [trying to analyze irelevant things](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59725846/problem-scanning-and-scanning-data-from-file#comment105602703_59725846) does not [Win Friends](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/How_to_Win_Friends_and_Influence_People).  Consider another approach.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Your code is incomplete; in particular, it seems to be missing a `main()` function and at least one `#include`. Please [edit] your code so it's a [mcve] of your problem (including any necessary inputs, but preferably not needing any), then we can try to reproduce and solve it. You should also read [ask].

Answer (score 1):

The problem you are having is your format string and your failure to validate the read against all 4 successful conversions per iteration. For your format string you can use:

```
" %20[^,],%d,%d,%c|"
```

(the leading space is optional, but required if you have space following the `'|'` before the next name. Also note, if you have the potential for space surrounding the final `active` character, you can handle that by including a space in your format string to consume any-and-all whitespace, e.g. `" %20[^,],%d,%d, %c |"`)

An example reading a line with multiple sets of movie information could be:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAXN 21     /* if you need a constant, #define one (or more) */

int main (int argc, char **argv) {
    char name[MAXN], active;
    int code, seasons;
    /* use filename provided as 1st argument (stdin by default) */
    FILE *fp = argc > 1 ? fopen (argv[1], "r") : stdin;

    if (!fp) {  /* validate file open for reading */
        perror ("file open failed");
        return 1;
    }

    while (fscanf (fp, " %20[^,],%d,%d,%c|", 
                    name, &code, &seasons, &active) == 4) {
        printf ("\nname   : %s\ncode   : %d\nseason : %d\nactive : %c\n",
                name, code, seasons, active);
    }

    if (fp != stdin)   /* close file if not stdin */
        fclose (fp);
}
```

**Example Input File**

```
$ cat dat/movies.txt
The Universe,2,3,Y|Zoo,7,3,N|The Hobbit,10,2,Y|True Lies,12,25,N|Animals,22,2,Y| Euphoria,35,5,Y
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/readmovies dat/movies.txt

name   : The Universe
code   : 2
season : 3
active : Y

name   : Zoo
code   : 7
season : 3
active : N

name   : The Hobbit
code   : 10
season : 2
active : Y

name   : True Lies
code   : 12
season : 25
active : N

name   : Animals
code   : 22
season : 2
active : Y

name   : Euphoria
code   : 35
season : 5
active : Y
```

Look things over and let me know if you have further questions. There is more than one way to do this, but this is the closest to your original.

Comment: Yep, caught and changed `:)`

Comment: this is almost identicle to what i have and even when i change to this it doesnt work it drives me crazy because there is no reason for this to happen..

Comment: How did you create your data file? Is it created on Win10 with UTF-16 character set? That will cause all kinds of problems unless you switch to using a wide-character type. What OS are you on?

Comment: the problem i have is that it when to input is The Hobbit,10,2,Y per say (or any other 1 bigger the 2nd scan fails

Comment: im on windows 10, im not sure about the data i the file was sent to me how do i check

Comment: The only constraints on your input is the 20 character name. The integers will handle anything from `-2147483648  to  2147483647` and so long as the final character is just a single 8-bit character, it will be read into `active` without a problem. If your file actually contains characters that are 16-bits wide -- then yes, that will cause problems.

Comment: Hold on, let me look up a hex-dump for windows. Just use [Format-Hex](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/format-hex?view=powershell-7) and post your output.

Comment: no i checked it shows on the bottom of the txt file its UTF-8 but now it seems to get only the first digit on the 2nd scan but everything else works

Comment: You have UTF-8 with a [Byte Order Mark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) at the beginning of the file. Windows Notepad writes a byte-order-mark by default. You will have fits with data files on Win10, unless you get an editor that lets you control the output file format. [Notepad++](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/downloads/) and [Geany](https://github.com/geany/geany) are two good ones that do. If you are feeling brave [Vim for Windows](https://www.vim.org/download.php) is another fantastic (text) programming editor.

Comment: doesnt work either im just dropping this it shouldnt be happening yet it still doesnt work i have nowhere to go from here..

Comment: Do you have a way to post a link to the data file you are using? I can boot into Win10 and see what is going on. You are right -- this shouldn't be happening, but MS has a way of making it difficult intentionally. If you post a link, I'm happy to help further -- or email to drankinatty at good ole gmail and I'll get it.

Comment: i really appreciate it but im already 12 hours staring at a screen that progressed nowhere im done

Comment: No worries -- we have all been there. There is a simple explanation, and we will figure it out. We just have to take it step-by-step. At this point, you don't have a programming problem, we have a file-content problem. It's not uncommon for professors to get new Win10 machines and have no clue about the file content they create until things start breaking.....